# (SVM) Difference between linear kernel and polynomial kernel of degree 1?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am new to machine learning. Could anyone tell me the difference between linear kernel and polynomial kernel of degree 1 wrt SVM (if there is any difference)?

The reason I asked, I am getting different accuracy for both on the spam dataset from UCI.

Answer (score 2):

There is no **mathematical** difference, but implementation-wise they will be solved in a different fashion and could have different **default values**. So if you are observing different results - these are due to implementation (and so - particular library etc.), not - math behind it.

Comment: Thank you. 
I am using sklearn package (internally using libSVM). I saw the documentation on the sklearn webpage and they actually mentioned a gamma factor multiplied for the polynomial kernel. [I don't understand why?!]

Comment: Note that "LinearSVC" in sklearn is **not** what is usually called SVM. They take a square of the hinge loss and they penalise bias term too. With respect to gamma - it gives some more flexibility for polynomial kernel (as there is also coef0, the bias term of the kernel itself, and gamma controls to some extent their effects). In general - set gamma to 1 and coef0 to 0 to get as close as possible with this library.